# Populate Marker with current location in MapsActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have successfully developed a program to update the marker as the user travels, however the text will only say "Current Location"

I would also like to populate the marker with Address information to the user when clicked. Below are some snippets of code emphasizing my intention, any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Here is my current MapsActivity.java

```
 import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Camera;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private GoogleApiClient client;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;
        private Location lastLocation;
        private Marker currentLocationMarker;
        public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
        TextView textView;
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                checkLocationPermission();
            }

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
           switch(requestCode)
           {
               case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
                   if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                   {
                       //permission is granted
                       if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                           if(client == null){
                               buildGoogleApiClient();
                           }
                           mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                       }
                   }
               else  {
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       //Permission is denied
                   }
                   return;
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Click Icon in Top right for Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mMap = googleMap;
            LatLng Phoenix = new LatLng(33.6056711, -112.4052378);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Phoenix).title("Default Location: Phoenix, AZ"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Phoenix));


           if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }
        }

            protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
                 client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

                 client.connect();
            }


        @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;

    if(currentLocationMarker != null){
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
 }

 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
 MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
 markerOptions.position(latLng);
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));


    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

 String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String area = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
 String city = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
 String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
 String postalcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

 String fullAddress = address+", "+area+", " +city+", " + country+ "," + postalcode;

        textView.setText(fullAddress);

 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

    if(client != null){
 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
 }

}

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
            }
        }

        public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
                }
                else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

        public void onZoom(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomIn) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            }
            if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomOut) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
            }
        }

        public void ChangeType(View view) {
            if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Satellite Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hybrid Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Terrain Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Normal Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }


        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }
```

Here is the corresponding xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img_header" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

StackTrace

```
05-17 09:15:49.411 15842-15842/edu.phoenix.mbl402.week3apptt2163 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.phoenix.mbl402.week3apptt2163, PID: 15842
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
    at edu.phoenix.mbl402.week3apptt2163.MapsActivity.onLocationChanged(MapsActivity.java:139)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzay.notifyListener(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder.notifyListenerInternal(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ListenerHolder$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source:16)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;

    if(currentLocationMarker != null){
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(getAddressForLatLng());
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker((markerOptions));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

}


public static Address getAddressForLatLng(Context context, LatLng location) {
    final int MAX_RESULTS = 1;
    final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    Address address = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        final List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, MAX_RESULTS);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() != 0) {
            address = addresses.get(0);
        }
        return address;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Geocoding", "Geocoding was not possible");
    }
    return address;
}
```

Comment: please post full code.

Comment: Full Code has been posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to remove marker from map on each location update. reuse existing marker store reference to it.

`Marker mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()......)`

After creating mMarkerObject refresh its location in OnLocationChanged

`mMarker.setTitle()
 mMarker.setPosition(latLng);`

If for some reason You still want to implement on click action
add interface to Your main activity OnMarkerClickListener and override OnMarkerClick and use showInfoWindow or something :)

EDIT: for geocrush try following ->

```
public static Address getAddressForLatLng(final Context context, final LatLng location) {
    final int MAX_RESULTS = 1;
    final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    Address address = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        final List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, MAX_RESULTS);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() != 0) {
            address = addresses.get(0);
        }
        return address;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Geocoding", "Geocoding was not possible");
    }
    return address;
}
```

Simplified more efficient version of onLocationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
lastLocation = location;

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
currentLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);
// make sure following setTitle gets String from getAddressForLatLng
currentLocationMarker.setTitle(getAddressForLatLng(latLng));

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

Comment: Hm, even after implementation the application still wants to crash upon opening with the following line: addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);. I believe I may be requesting latitude/longitude the incorrect way? 

Can you help me with what the final OnLocationChanged would look like? Thanks for the help

Comment: Index out of bound. try to do something like above edited

Comment: geocoder may return empty adress so nullpointer check is needed.
You may try different geocoder. 
for testing purpouses try logging geocoder response and change locations or try testing geocoder with onMapLongClickListener.

Comment: Please check my "Final Edit" for what my current two sections of code look like. Currently I am still receiving an error to Change Signature of getAddressLatlng

Comment: Because markerOptions.title() expects string and Your method returns Address object :) change Your method to return String with needed data. 
I still dont see point to create new marker each time . You can remove MarkerOptions from Your method and reuse existing marker and change title location etc. here is link to available methods from documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

Comment: Added in my answer onLocationChanged implementation with reusing existing marker rather than creating new one

Comment: Please check my comments above and mark answer if was helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reverse geocoding](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address) to get a human-readable address string from your  latitude and longitude.
Then use that address as the marker title, instead of `"Current Location"`.
Specifically:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                // In this sample, get just a single address.
                1);
address = adresses[0];
markerOptions.title(address);
```

(Error handling etc. left out, see link).

Comment: I have added something similar above in my onLocationChanged class however it is not currently working

Comment: Can you give more details on what is happening? Is it returning anything at all?

Comment: Of course, it is displaying the current user location upon clicking the top right icon.. however the text simply says "Current Location", as mentioned in my code. Im looking to alter it in a way to display the actual graphical data

Comment: ^^^ This takes place when the OnLocationChanged code is taken out. However when it is implemented the application is crashing. I assume I have overlapped code somewhere?

Comment: I can't be sure without doing more in-depth debugging. One possibility is that you removed the marker title, that could be causing a crash.

Comment: But if I include the marker title won't it just display a static value? Are we allowed to share contact information, I would love some help

Comment: You could use the same address for the text view and the marker title.

Comment: Even with, " markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(textView));" it is still crashing

Comment: Hmm, marker title isn't required. So it must be some data access. Perhaps not all of the address fields are well defined for some addresses. Can you paste the stack trace?

Comment: Added to the original post

Comment: So the call to the geocoder isn't returning an address. Try using this tool with that LatLng https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/

Comment: When I change to: "addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);" It states that latitude and longitude symbols cannot be resolved. Should they be called something different??

Comment: This line has the error, but why?  

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);